# Seeking suggestions for online exhibit platform

Tags: browser, cms

I am building a virtual exhibit, i.e. a web-based version of a museum exhibit.
I am looking for a platform (free or commercial) that can create a rich user experience in the browser, with a straightforward CMS-like back end. 
By rich user experience I mean:
 - slick animated transitions between pages and states
 - flexible use of audio, video, and images
 - pre-made exhibit templates for navigation and content pages, with options for customization
 - possible integration of social media (simple sharing and commenting)
 - possibility of making interactive games/activities
 - great cross-browser compatibility, and W3C conformance

If you of any tools like this, please let me know.
I have found some tools that include museum cataloguing systems, and other infrastructure that museums use. I'm just looking for something to churn out beautiful interactive educational web-sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to clarify the requirements, you need:

- full W3C compliance
- social media integration
- full support for creating interactive games
- support video
- support audio
- premade templates that are
- also easy to customize
- and accommodate animated content transitions with complex navigation

all wrapped up in a

- existing, straightforward CMS

Unfortunately, the first 8 bullet points counter the last one.

You are asking for something quite robust and versatile. A straightforward CMS tends to be more narrowly focused as it has to appeal to a specific task list to remain straightforward.

What I'd suggest is that you not try to make this as 'rich' as the requirements state. 'Rich' is usually code for 'cumbersome' from a UX perspective. Consider leveraging existing social media to handle your media. Facebook is great for comments. Flickr is ideal for photos. Youtube is the easiest way to share video out there. Connect that all in something simple...maybe a Wordpress install. Leverage the existing tools out there rather than trying to invent a massive CMS that likely will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: JQuery UI + HTML5 is actually pretty much all of those except for being a CMS. This of course requires someone with coding skill and someone to fill the content. I don't have much experience with CMS though so I can hardly comment on that aspect.